# C++ chooses 'wrong' overloaded method with default parameters

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, overloading, default-parameters

I have the following interface

```
virtual void send_command( const std::string& command, const std::string& key, const std::string& value, bool pipeline = true );    
virtual void send_command( const std::string& command, const std::string& key, bool pipeline = true );
virtual void send_command( const std::string& command, bool pipeline = true );
```

that is fully implemented in one class which I will then call as the following:

```
c.send_command("MUTLI");
c.send_command("SET", "foo", "bar");
c.send_command("GET", "foo");
c.send_command("EXEC");
```

When I check which method implementation get's called, I see that the third call (*GET foo*) ends up to hit the last implementation:

```
virtual void send_command( const std::string& command, bool pipeline = true );
```

where "foo" is implicit converted to bool. The same counts for *"SET", "foo", "bar"* which hits the second implementation (string, string, bool)
When I make the call with an explicit c-cast to a string like this

```
c.send_command("GET", (std::string)"foo");
```

The expected method gets called.

I am using gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8) with C++11.

Comment: Do the default parameters have anything to do with this?

Comment: Yes, in some cases I want to set them to false, so `c.send_command("GET", "foo", false)` works as well

Comment: I don't see how that is related to the problem you are reporting.

Comment: Well, I don't want to put casts in every method call. Why is the second parameter converted from string to bool and how can I avoid that?

Comment: c.send_command("GET", std::string("foo")); will call the one that you want

Comment: To avoid that, you may write the `send_command` version taking a `const char*`

Comment: I would expect that `c.send_command("SET", "foo", "bar");` also calls `virtual void send_command( const std::string& command, const std::string& key, bool pipeline = true );`

Comment: Yes, in fact it does. Sorry about being inconsistent - will edit my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're hitting the fact that pointers can implicitly be converted to `bool` (testing that they're not null), and that a string literal is not a `std::string`, but a `const char[]` which decays into a `const char*` on call. What you can do is provide an additional overload taking a `const char*`:

```
void send_command(const std::string& command, const char* key)
{ send_command(command, std::string(key)); }
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/t3fOGu)

Comment: Well, that's an option. But `std::string key = "key"; client->send_command( "GET", key );` will lead to the same behaviour. Does this mean, that the std::string is represented as const char?

Comment: @Tobi Sure, but I kinda assume you want to call it with arbitrary literals, and not have to define a variable for each one.

Comment: There are fixed strings in unit tests, but there will be string instances in prod use

Comment: +1 And that has absolutely nothing to do with default parameters.

Comment: @Tobi I don't quite understand your question "Does this mean, that the std::string is represented as const char?" `std::string` is a `std::string`. A string literal (such as `"foo"`) is not an instance of `std::string`, it's a `const char [4]`. Does that answer you?

Comment: @Angew yes, it should be that way - but I tried to create an instance of std::string and pass it to the send_command (very first comment). That still did not fix the conversion to bool. I am not sure whether there are compiler optimizations turned on or not.

Comment: @Tobi Oh, I misunderstood slightly. But you must have made something else wrong - it's impossible for `std::string key = "key"; client->send_command( "GET", key );` to call the `(std::string, bool)` overload - `std::string` does not have a conversion to `bool`, simple as that.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler prefers the conversion from `const char*` to `bool` over a conversion to a UDT (`std::string`). If needed, just add more overloads for `const char*` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Overload resolution has several steps: First, a set of *viable* functions is selected. These viable functions must have enough parameters for the call, considering ellipsis and/or default arguments. In addition, each argument has to be convertible to the corresponding parameter type. For `c.send_command("GET", "foo");` you have as viable candidates

```
virtual void send_command( const std::string&, const std::string&, bool);
virtual void send_command( const std::string&, bool);
```

because the third parameter of the former is defaulted and the string literal arguments are convertible to `string const&` and `bool`.

After having the viable set, the compiler looks at the argument conversions needed. No conversion is prefered, then builtin conversions, then user defined conversions. In this case, the conversion for the first argument is the same in both viable functions. For the second argument, the conversion to `bool` is buitlin, while the conversion to `string const&` is not. Therefore `send_command( const std::string&, bool);` is prefered over the alternative.